# Trying to modify a game so that the program keeps a list of unaccepted answers and prints them at the end. (java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program a picnic game that keeps a list of all the items that were rejected (but only one occurrence of each|if the user enters an item twice and it is rejected both times, it should appear only once in the list of rejected items). At the end of the game, prints out all the rejected items and the number of times the user's answer was rejected. I'm supposed to use an array list. what should I do? here's what I have so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PlayPicnic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Picnic picnic = new Picnic();

        while (picnic.numberOfItems() < 5)
        {
            System.out.print("What do you want to bring on the picnic? ");
            String item = scan.nextLine();
            if (picnic.okayToBring(item))
            {
                picnic.add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nHere's what we'll have at the picnic:");
        picnic.show();

    }
}
```

and heres the corresponding picnic class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Picnic
{
    // INSTANCE VARIABLES:
    private ArrayList<String> stuffToBring; // items to bring on the picnic

    // CONSTRUCTOR:

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Construct a new Picnic.
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public Picnic()
    {
        stuffToBring = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize list
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Given an item s, see if it's okay to add it to the list.
    // Return true if it is, false otherwise:
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public boolean okayToBring(String s)
    {
        // "Secret rule" -- s can't be an item already in the list:
        if (stuffToBring.contains(s)) // "contains" is in the ArrayList class
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Given an item s, add it to the list (if it's okay to add it)
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public void add(String s)
    {
        if (okayToBring(s)) 
        {
            stuffToBring.add(s);
        }

    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Print the items in the list
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stuffToBring.size(); i++)
        {
            String s = stuffToBring.get(i);
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // ALTERNATE APPROACH USING A "for next" LOOP:
        //        for (String s: stuffToBring)
        //        {
        //            System.out.println(s);
        //        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the number of items in the list:
    //-----------------------------------------------------
    public int numberOfItems()
    {
        return stuffToBring.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood your question, but it seems quite easy: add an `ArrayList<String>` and insert the `item` in the `else` inside the `while`. Then, after `picnic.show()`, you just print the `ArrayList`.

Here's the code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Picnic picnic = new Picnic();
ArrayList<String> unaccepted = new ArrayList<>();

while (picnic.numberOfItems() < 5)
{
    System.out.print("What do you want to bring on the picnic? ");
    String item = scan.nextLine();
    if (picnic.okayToBring(item))
    {
        picnic.add(item);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!unaccepted.contains(item)) unaccepted.add(item);
        System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);
    }
}

System.out.println("\nHere's what we'll have at the picnic:");
picnic.show();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(unaccepted.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array list

```
 ArrayList<String> rejectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you reject an offer

```
System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);
```

You add the item to the list of rejected items

```
System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);
rejectedItems.add(item);
```

If you NEED to use an ArrayList, at this point you would also need to run through the list and make sure the item you're adding isn't already there as ArrayLists allow duplicates.

At the end, you print them all out

```
for (String item : rejectedItems)
{
   System.out.println("Rejected " + item);
}
```

Comment: A Set would probably be better than an ArrayList for the rejected items, since the poster says 'if the user enters an item twice and it is rejected both times, it should appear only once in the list of rejected items.'

Comment: But he also says "I'm supposed to use an array list", so I'm guessing it's some validation code he needs on an ArrayList

Comment: Ross, that's a good point. I assumed it meant just "use ArrayList somewhere in the code." If he meant he needed to use it for the rejected items as well, then the answer posted by @StepTNT would be more correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another ArrayList to keep track of unaccepted items.
As you are not adding duplicated items to unaccepted ArrayList you should also keep track of the number of wrong answers.
Here is a very basic solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlayPicnic {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      Picnic picnic = new Picnic();
      ArrayList<String> unaccepted = new ArrayList<String>();
      int wrongAttempts = 0;

      while (picnic.numberOfItems() < 5) {
         System.out.print("What do you want to bring on the picnic? ");
         String item = scan.nextLine();
         if (picnic.okayToBring(item)) {
            picnic.add(item);
         } else {
            wrongAttempts++;
            if (!unaccepted.contains(item)) {
               unaccepted.add(item);
            }
            System.out.println("Sorry, you can't bring " + item);
         }
      }

      System.out.println("\nHere's what we'll have at the picnic:");
      picnic.show();
      System.out.println("Unaccepted items");
      for (String item : unaccepted) {
         System.out.println(item);
      }
      System.out.println("Your answer was rejected " + wrongAttempts + " times");

   }
}
```